# selectable NSTextField and NSColorPanel – how to break their undesired interplay?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nscolorpanel, nscolorwell

In a seemingly trivial setup, I encounter an undesired interplay between a selectable **NSTextField** and an **NSColorPanel** that I cannot get rid of and that drives me nuts.

Here’s the setup: Within one window, I have a selectable **Multi-Line Label** (de facto an **NSTextField**) and an **NSColorWell**.

The **Color Well** allows the user to color geometric objects in the GUI; it has nothing to do with text whatsoever. Of course, clicking on the color well *activates* it, i.e. brings up the shared **NSColorPanel** and connects the color well to it.

The **Text Field** is completely independent from the colored objects in the GUI and presents data to the user. It is read-only, i.e. **not editable**. Since the data is organized in columns, I use tabs for text formatting and the `setAttributedStringValue:` method of **NSTextField** to display the data.

At first glimpse, everything works as you would expect in a such a trivial setup.

But here comes the rub: I want the user to be able to copy the data in the text field to process it elsewhere. Therefore, the **NSTextField** has to be **selectable**. And setting it to be `selectable` is where the problems start:

When the user clicks on the selectable text field to select the text, the window’s **field editor** takes over, and as a consequence, all the tab settings of the attributed text are lost and the text gets mingled. The usual way to prevent this is to set the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property of the **NSTextField** to `YES`. If I do this, the tab formatting is preserved when the user selects the text. **But** now the **NSColorPanel** (if visible) unintentionally *also* switches to the text color (always black), and if the color well is *active* (connected to the **NSColorPanel**), it will remain active, thereby changing the color of all geometric GUI objects to black. Ouch!

I have found no way to set the `selectable` and `allowsEditingTextAttributes` properties of **NSTextField** to `YES` but still prevent it from communicating with the **NSColorPanel**.

The obvious alternative route would be to preserve the tab formatting for selected text even with `allowsEditingTextAttributes` set to `NO` (which would disconnect the color panel from the text field, as desired). But I’ve had no success with this approach either, although I do not really understand why:

My idea was to set the required tabs as the `defaultParagraphStyle` of the field editor of the text field. So, I set up a customized field editor:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        NSArray *myTabs = @[
            [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType:NSRightTabStopType location:100],
            [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType:NSRightTabStopType location:200],
            [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType:NSRightTabStopType location:300]
        ];
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *myParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        [myParagraphStyle setTabStops:myTabs];

        myFieldEditor = [NSTextView new]; // myFieldEditor is an instance variable
        [myFieldEditor setDefaultParagraphStyle:myParagraphStyle];

        [window setDelegate:self];
        [window fieldEditor:YES forObject:myTextField];
    }
```

And activate it for the text field in the `windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:` delegate method:

```
- (id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(id)client
    {
        if (client == myTextField) return myFieldEditor;
        return nil;
    }
```

I even made sure that my custom field editor is indeed used by subclassing the **NSTextFieldCell** of my text field and logging the propagated field editor:

```
@implementation myTextFieldCell

- (NSText *)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText *)textObj
    {
        NSTextView *newTextObj = (NSTextView*)[super setUpFieldEditorAttributes:textObj];
        NSLog(@"STYLE: %@", [newTextObj defaultParagraphStyle]);
        return newTextObj;
    }

@end
```

Now, when I select the text in the text field, I get the following log output:

```
2017-11-02 11:51:07.432 Demo[94807:303] STYLE: Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (
    100R,
    200R,
    300R
), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0.05, HeaderLevel 0
```

Which is exactly what is expected.

But *still*, the tab formatting disappears in the text field as soon as I select the text. I have no idea why this does not work.

So I’m stuck either way. If I set the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property of **NSTextField** to `YES`, tab formatting is preserved when the text is selected, but my colored objects in the GUI unintentionally change to black. If I set the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property to `NO`, the color panel behaves as it should, but the tab formatting is lost as soon as I select the text.

This is a very unfortunate case of Cocoa trying to be too smart and thereby making a completely trivial setup a huge issue.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I’m aware that a “last resort” solution would be to use the `setUpFieldEditorAttributes:` method of `myTextFieldCell` to deactivate the color well (i.e. disconnect the color panel from the color well). This way, the color panel would change to black, but at least the colored GUI objects would not. But that’s not what I want; I want the color panel to stay connected to the color well, but not change to black.

Comment: Why do you use a text field instead of a text view? To disconnect a text view and the color panel, switch `usesFontPanel` off.

Comment: @Willeke A text view has a lot of features I do not need/want (scrollbars, frame around the text area, …). It might be possible to “dumb it down” to a kind of text field with a lot of effort, but I haven’t tried this; I wasn’t aware that `usesFontPanel` would also switch off the **color** panel. But if so, that again raises the question why that wouldn’t work with the text view that is the field editor of the text field (which it doesn’t – just tested it). In short: customizing the field editor does not seem to have any effect at all, and I don’t know why.

Comment: Investigating further, I made the text field editable and for both the default field editor and the custom field editor for this text field, I set `usesFontPanel` to `NO`. Turns out I can still change the fonts in the text field with the Font Panel! So somehow customizing the field editor does not work, at least as I configure it, and it seems to me increasingly that this is at the heart of the issue.

Comment: It seems that the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property of **NSTextField** completely overwrites the field editor. If it’s `YES`, I can edit fonts even with `usesFontPanel` set to `NO` in the field editor. If it’s `NO`, I cannot edit fonts even with `usesFontPanel` set to `YES` in the field editor. And the same seems to be true for respecting the tab settings in the paragraph style. But then, what is the field editor good for in the first place?

Comment: You can switch of the frame and the scroll bars of a text view. But if you want to use a text field, switch off `usesFontPanel` in `setUpFieldEditorAttributes:`. The field editor makes it possible to edit and select the text of a text field. `fieldEditor` of `myFieldEditor` should be `YES`.

Comment: As I tried to point out, switching off `usesFontPanel` in `setUpFieldEditorAttributes:`simply has no effect at all. It will always be overwritten by the value of `allowsEditingTextAttributes`: If that is `YES`, the Font panel *will* work, regardless of the `usesFontPanel` setting. If it is `NO`, tabStops simply don’t work, regardless of the `defaultParagraphStyle` of the field editor. Given that mess, you’re probably right with your **NSTextView** suggestion. I just jib at instantiating a scroll and a clip view I don’t want and need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I ended up with the suggestion that @Willeke (thanks!!) made in his comment to my question: To use **NSTextView** instead of **NSTextField** to implement my **Multi-Line Label**.

I will first sum up why it seems impossible to do what I wanted with **NSTextField**, and then the solution with **NSTextView**.

### Why NSTextField doesn’t work

As described, my idea for a solution was to customize the field editor for the **NSTextField**, setting the tab stops I need, so that I need not set **NSTextField**’s `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property to `YES` (which would unintentionally couple the text field to the color panel). This, I hoped, would preserve the tab stops of my attributed string’s paragraph style when I select the text in the text field and thereby activate the field editor.

Extensive testing has shown that this does not work for several reasons:

1. As @Willeke pointed out, setting the `usesFontPanel` property of **NSTextView** to `NO` also breaks the connection of the text view to the color panel (as desired). However, this does not work for the **NSTextView** that is the field editor of the **NSTextField**, because in this context, this setting is always overwritten by the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property of the **NSTextField**: If `allowsEditingTextAttributes` is `YES`, the font and color panels are coupled regardless of the value of `usesFontPanel`, if it is `NO`, the font and color panels are decoupled regardless of the value of `usesFontPanel`.
2. The idea to use the tab stops of a customized field editor instead of using the tab stops of my attributed string’s paragraph style (which would require `allowsEditingTextAttributes` to be `YES`) wouldn’t work, anyway, because the tab stops settings of the field editor are obviously always completely ignored by **NSTextField**, regardless of the value of the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property. **NSTextField** *always* uses the evenly spaced default tab stops.

Judging from intense googling, the *other variant* – setting `allowsEditingTextAttributes` to `YES` but somehow modifying **NSColorPanel** to not connect to the **NSTextField** nevertheless – is impossible to implement without recurring to private methods of **NSColorPanel**.

### How to implement the solution with NSTextView

While it seems overkill to instantiate a complete **NSTextView** embedded in a clip view and a scroll view just to get the functionality of a text field, in the end it’s the easiest (or even only possible) solution.

To make the scroll view disappear, you’ll have to basically uncheck everything in the **NSScrollView**’s *Attribute* inspector in IB, in particular *Show Vertical Scroller*. Set *Draw Background* and the border type to the kind of appearance you want; if you want to mimic a multi-line label (like I did), uncheck *Draw Background* and choose the invisible border type. In the *Attribute* inspector of the embedded **NSTextView**, also uncheck all attributes except *Selectable*, in particular *Uses Font Panel*.

Make sure the size of the **NSTextView** is large enough to hold the complete content string to avoid unintentional scrolling effects and fix the text position. If your content string ends with a line brake, you’ll need enough space for an empty line beneath it. If you did *not* uncheck *Draw Background* and this does not look the way you want, don’t draw the background of either the **NSScrollView** or the **NSTextView**, select the invisible border for **NSScrollView** and then put an **NSBox** of the desired size and appearance beneath them.

You can now set the attributed content string with:

```
[[myTextView textStorage] setAttributedString:myAttributedString];
```

Note that this does work although the `editable` property of **NSTextView** is set to `NO` since you’re modifying the **NSTextStorage**, not the **NSTextView** itself.

But unfortunately, we’re not finished yet.

When you’re using an **NSTextField** to display readonly data as you typically do in a **Label**, more often than not you would not want the text field to be part of your key view loop (that circles through your controls by pressing the Tab key). To achieve this, you can simply set the `refusesFirstResponder` property of **NSTextField** to `YES`. But **NSTextView** does not inherit from **NSControl** and therefore does not have this property. So in the end, we’ll have to subclass **NSTextView** to add the `refusesFirstResponder` property.

The implementation overwrites `becomeFirstResponder` and goes like this:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
    {
        if (!_refusesFirstResponder) return [super becomeFirstResponder];

        NSEvent *event = [NSApp currentEvent];
        if ([event type] == NSLeftMouseDown || [event type] == NSRightMouseDown) return [super becomeFirstResponder];

        NSView *validKeyView = ([event modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask)? [[[self previousValidKeyView] previousValidKeyView] previousValidKeyView] : [self nextValidKeyView];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{[[self window] makeFirstResponder:validKeyView];}];
        return NO;
    }
```

If `refusesFirstResponder` is `NO`, we simply return **super**’s implementation.

If it is `YES`, we check if the **NSTextView** is about to become first responder because of a mouse click within it. If so, we also simply return **super**’s implementation, thereby allowing text selection with the mouse.

Other than that, we forward the first responder request to the next or previous key view (depending on whether the *Shift* key was pressed) and return `NO`, refusing to become first responder. Determining the previous key view is a bit tricky because the closest previous key view is the embedding **NSClipView** we don’t want or need, but have to use because Interface Builder does not offer a “pure” **NSTextView**. Then comes the embedding **NSScrollView**, and only then the previous key view we actually want.

Also, since we’re amidst a process which determines the first responder, we cannot simply invoke `makeFirstResponder:`, but have to postpone it to the next iteration of the run loop.

Now that we have implemented `refusesFirstResponder`, we’ll still have to mimic **NSTextField**’s behavior to dismiss any text selection when it loses first responder state. We can do this in an **NSText** delegate method. Assuming we don’t need other delegate functionality,  we can make our subclass its own delegate and add this delegate method:

```
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
        [[notification object] setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(UINT64_MAX, 0)];
    }
```

Finally, if we have to subclass, anyway, we might as well add a `setAttributedString:` convenience method.

So what we’ll end up with is this:

#### Header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface MyTextFieldLikeTextView : NSTextView <NSTextViewDelegate>

@property IBInspectable BOOL    refusesFirstResponder;

- (void)setAttributedString:(NSAttributedString*)attributedString;

@end
```

#### Implementation:

```
#import "MyTextFieldLikeTextView.h"

@implementation MyTextFieldLikeTextView

- (void)awakeFromNib
    {
        [self setDelegate:self];
    }

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
    {
        if (!_refusesFirstResponder) return [super becomeFirstResponder];

        NSEvent *event = [NSApp currentEvent];
        if ([event type] == NSLeftMouseDown || [event type] == NSRightMouseDown) return [super becomeFirstResponder];

        NSView *validKeyView = ([event modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask)? [[[self previousValidKeyView] previousValidKeyView] previousValidKeyView] : [self nextValidKeyView];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{[[self window] makeFirstResponder:validKeyView];}];
        return NO;
    }

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
        [[notification object] setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(UINT64_MAX, 0)];
    }

- (void)setAttributedString:(NSAttributedString*)attributedString
    {
        [[self textStorage] setAttributedString:attributedString];
    }

@end
```

Still a lot of effort only because Cocoa tries to outsmart us and insists on connecting the **NSColorPanel** to each and every **NSTextField** that allows for attributed text …